# Do floating points have more precision if calculated at with a range of high values rather than low values?

Tags: c#, floating-accuracy

Would a higher range of floats be more accurate to multiply / divide /  add / subtract, than a lower range.

For example, would `567.56 / 345.54` be more accurate than `.00097854 / .00021297` ?

Comment: I *think* that the lower values are more accurate - but it's been a while since I had to worry about this sort of thing. Run some experiments to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is "no." Floating point numbers are (usually*) represented with a normalized mantissa and an exponent.  Multiplication and division operate first on the normalized mantissa, then on the exponents.

Addition and subtraction are, of course, another story.  Operations like your examples:

```
 567.56 + 345.54 or .00097854 - .00021297
```

work fine.  But operations with disparate orders of magnitude like

```
 567.56 + .00097854    or  345.54  - .00021297
```

may lose some low-order precision.

- The IEEE Floating point standards includes denormalized numbers. If you are an astrophysicist or runtime-library developer, you may need to understand them.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Comment: The first Pentium came out in 1994, and turned out to have a defect in the division logic.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number  Here's the joke.  It's Christmas 1994, and Andy Grove (Intel's boss) has had a pretty good year.  He walks into a bar and orders a shot of 27-year-old single malt scotch whiskey to celebrate.  The bartender says, "that will be $20, sir." Grove puts a twenty dollar bill on the bar, looks at it for a moment, and says "keep the change."

Comment: Denormalized numbers are also encountered in audio and other signal-processing applications, particularly where infinite impulse response filters are used (as with echo effects). The echo decreases over time and, when the input remains zero, the echo eventually reaches the denormalized range.

Answer (score 1):

For IEEE 754 binary floating-point numbers (the most common), floating-point values have the same number of bits in the significand throughout most of the exponent range. However, there is a portion of the range where the significand has effectively fewer bits. And the relative error caused by rounding does vary depending on where the significand lies within its range.

IEEE 754 floating-point numbers are represented by a sign (+1 or -1, encoded as 0 or 1), an exponent (for double-precision, -1022 to 1023, encoded as the exponent plus 1023, so 1 to 2046), and a significand (for double-precision, a fraction usually from 1 to just under 2, represented with 53 bits but encoded with 52 bits because the first bit is implicitly 1).

E.g., the number 6.5 is encoded with the bits 0 (sign +1), 10000000001 (exponent 2), and 1010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (binary fraction 1.1010, hex 1.a, decimal 1.3125). We can write this in hexadecimal floating-point as 0x1.ap2 (hex fraction 1.a multiplied by 2 to the power of decimal 2). Writing in hexadecimal floating-point enables humans to see the floating-point representation fairly easily.

For the exponent, the encoding values of 0 and 2047 are special. When the encoding is 0, the exponent is the same as when the encoding is 1 (-1022), but the implicit bit of the fraction is 0 instead of 1. When the encoding is 2047, the floating-point object represents infinity (if the significand bits are all zero) or a NaN (otherwise).

When the encoded exponent is 0 and the significand bits are all zero, the number represents zero (with +0 and -0 distinguished by the sign). If the significand bits are not all zero, the number is said to be denormalized. This is because most numbers are “normalized” by adjusting the exponent so that the fraction is between 1 (inclusive) and 2 (exclusive). For denormalized numbers, the fraction is less than 1; it starts with “0.” instead of “1.”.

When the result of a floating-point operation is a denormalized number, it effectively has fewer bits in the significand. Thus, as numbers drop below 0x1p-1022 (2<sup>-1022</sup>), the effective precision decreases.

When numbers are in the normal range (not underflowing to denormals and not overflowing to infinity), then there are no differences in the significands of numbers with different exponents, so:

- (2a+2b)/2 has exactly the same result as a+b.
- (2a-2b)/2 has exactly the same result as a-b.
- (2ab)/2 has exactly the same result as ab.

Note, however, that the relative error can change. When a floating-point operation is performed, the exact mathematical result must be rounded to a representable value. This rounding can happen only in units representable by the significand. For a given exponent, the bits in the significand have a fixed value. So the last bit in the significand represents a certain value. That value is a greater portion of a significand near 1 than it is of a significand near 2.

For a double-precision result, the unit of least precision (ULP) is 1 part in 2<sup>52</sup> of the value of the greatest bit in the significand. When using round-to-nearest mode (the most common default), the greatest error is at most half of that, because, if the representable number in one direction is more than half an ULP away, the number in the other direction is less than half an ULP away. And the closer number is returned by a proper floating-point operation.

Thus, the maximum relative error in a result with a significand near 1 is slightly over 2<sup>-53</sup>, but the maximum relative error in a result with a significand near 2 is slightly under 2<sup>-54</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I have to disagree a bit and say **Yes**, it may matter somehow...
Indeed, if you perform 56756.0 / 34554.0, then you'll get the nearest representable Float to the exact mathematical result, with a single floating point rounding "error".
This is because 56756.0 and 34554.0 are representable exactly in floating point (single or double precision IEEE 754), and because according to IEEE 754 standard, operations perform an exact rounding operation (in default mode to the nearest).

If you write 567.56 / 345.54, then both numbers are not represented exactly in floating point in radix 2, so the result of this operation is cumulating 3 floating point rounding "errors".

Let's compare the result in Squeak Smalltalk in double precision (Float), converted to exact arithmetic (Fraction with arbitrary integer length at numerator and denominator):

```
((56756.0 / 34554.0) asFraction - (56756 / 34554)) asFloat.
-> -7.932275867322412e-17
```

So far, so good, the magnitude of error is less than or equal to half an ulp, as promised by IEEE 754:

```
(56756 / 34554) asFloat ulp / 2
-> 1.1102230246251565e-16
```

With cumulated rounding errors, you may get a larger error (but never a smaller):

```
((567.56 / 345.54) asFraction - (56756 / 34554)) asFloat
-> -3.0136736359825544e-16

((0.00056756 / 0.00034554) asFraction - (56756 / 34554)) asFloat
-> 3.647664511768385e-16
```

Above example is hard to generalize, and I perfectly agree with other answers: generally, **NO**, you should only care of relative precision.
... Unless maybe if you want to implement some function with very strict tolerance about round off errors...

Answer (score 0):

No. In the sense that there's the same number of significant digits available no matter what the order of magnitude (exponent part) of your number is.

Comment: This is not strictly true. For numbers under 0x1p-126 (in float) or 0x1p-1022 (in double), there is a loss of precision.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right, I disregarded subnormal numbers there. However, the numbers from the Original Poster were not close to being subnormal, and I wanted to give a "simple" answer.